# Making imports inside function with decorators

Tags: python, python-import, python-decorators

I was studying a python library for geoprocessing called [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio). When I found myself in the following issue.

They are making imports inside a function with a decorator.

From my knowledge, I understand that calling imports inside functions are againts good practices but does the decorator changes anything about it?

```
import rasterio.shutil


@click.command(short_help="Transform coordinates.")
@precision_opt
@click.pass_context
def transform(ctx, input, src_crs, dst_crs, precision):
    import rasterio.warp
```

As you can see there are some imports being made before the following function and the rasterio.warp inside the function...

Does the decorator changes anything in the way python interprets it?

Comment: No. The main problem with including imports inside a function is that it obscures the dependency of the current module on an external module. Decorating the function doesn't change that.